# xmlcast is returing null value in Db2

Tags: db2

I am always getting a null value from using **XMLCAST** function in Db2. But when using a normal function call it is returning value in xml format... as below query proper xml data is coming. function Getdatavalue is returning xml datatype. using Linux 8.2 and db2 11.5

```
 db2 "select sample.Getdatavalue(1,4504)) from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

in the above result we have some double quotes in output xml.

but once we have used xmlcast function as below, it is returning the hexa value of null. i am using MD5 hashing mechanism.

```
db2 "select HEX(HASH(xmlcast(sample.Getdatavalue(1,4504) as varchar(32672)),0)) as hash_val from sysibm.sysdummy1";
```

even once i tried without Hash it was returning null result for below query. it looks xmlcast is not working.

```
db2 "select xmlcast(sample.Getdatavalue(1,4504) as varchar(32672)) as hash_val from sysibm.sysdummy1";
```

is there any way to convert xml datatype to clob or varchar.

body of Getdatavalue as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sample.Getdatavalue (v1 smallint, v2 integer)
RETURNS xml
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE v_Data xml;
set v_Data = (SELECT XMLELEMENT( NAME "rt_ky_cmpnnt", 
XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "rt", XMLAttributes(rt.rt_field_add_val AS 
"rt_add_val",
rt.rt_name AS 
 "rt_name",
rt.rt_name AS 
 "rt_name",
rt.rt_val1 AS "rt_val1",
rt_lim AS "rt_lim",
rt.rt_val2 AS "rt__val2",
rt.rt_whole_val AS "rt_whole_val" ))order by 
rf.rt_num asc)OPTION null ON NULL)
FROM sample.cmpnnt_val rt inner join sample.field_val rf
on rf.abc=rt.abc
and rf.pqr=rt.pqr
and rt.xyz=rf.xyz
where rt.abc = v1
AND rt.bcd = v2 );
RETURN v_Data;
END!
```

can anyone please explain how to handle xmlcast.

Comment: What is your Db2 version and platform? Provide some sample input data that returns NULL. What is the definition of the function `Getdatavalue`? Assuming that XMLCAST works as defined in the docs, the problem is likely with your data or function.

Comment: Linux 8.2 and db2 11.5 version.

Comment: What is the purpose of the query, why do you need or want XMLCAST? If you query an XML value, it is converted to a string when returned as result

Comment: i want to do HASH function after the return xml from Getdatavalue. so need xmlcast because HASH function can't work on xml input. it works only in varchar. so i want xmlcast. if any other option please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a string from an XML value, use the function [XMLSERIALIZE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlserialize).

> The XMLSERIALIZE function returns a serialized XML value of the specified data type generated from the XML-expression argument.

Comment: My function is already return as xml data type. Need to convert return xml data from the function Getdatavalue to varchar and after converted return xml to varchar need to pass to HASH function. which is not working using xmlcast. will XMLSERIALIZE  convert xml data type to varchar.

Comment: see the doc link, yes